# ruby script/plugin discover RuntimeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update Ruby Gems from behind a Proxy (ISA-NTLM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm)

Having problems when running this command on a rails installation on windows under a corporate firewall:

> ruby script/plugin discover

I already set up the http_proxy variable on the system and this is the error I get:

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:203:in `open_http': Non-HTTP proxy URI: http-proxy(RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616:in `buffer_open'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164:in `open_loop'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `open_loop'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132:in `open_uri'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/plugin.rb:7
28:in `scrape'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/plugin.rb:7
02:in `parse!'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/plugin.rb:7
01:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/plugin.rb:7
01:in `parse!'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/plugin.rb:5
17:in `parse!'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/plugin.rb:5
33:in `parse!'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/plugin.rb:9
67
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `ge
m_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `re
quire'
        from script/plugin:3
```

Comment: Thanks, already tried that but I get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I used this: http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ as the Authentication Proxy