# How do I install rails on a Windows machine that uses a proxy server to get to the internet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I'm a big fan of the ruby way. However today it got in my way.

The defacto way of installing rails (i'm running as a domain user on a WinXP machine) is

- download and install ruby (one-click installer)
- type `>gem install rails` at the command prompt

Step 2 fails with some function getaddrhost not able to function. Some googling taught me that this is a known issue - [See Authenticating Windows Proxy Problems on the rubygems FAQ](http://rubygems.org/export/html/3)

The suggested options there to "use the `-p` or `--http-proxy http://proxy:port` " switch for gem install also didn't work any wonders.

There's a link to something that runs a server to get across the proxy server - but it looked like it would need python to be installed (??!!). So I gave that a miss.

I'm going to try to get the .gem files (after figuring out all the inter dependencies :( ) from `ruby_home\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\cache` on my rails-friendly home machine and USB-drive it across and do a local gem install. Does anyone have a less painful / quick way of bridging this divide?

**Update:**
Day2. Okay so I have the gems available locally. However if I do a

```
>gem install activesupport-1.4.4 --local
ERROR:  Error installing gem activesupport-1.4.4[.gem]: undefined method `includ
e?' for nil:NilClass
```

I've tried ruby once click installer for windows for 186-27 RC2 and 186-26 Final release. Same issue. More googling led to "[In case you're having trouble installing gems...](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2007/2/6/in-case-you-re-having-trouble-installing-gems)".
The latest workaround is to: delete the source_cache file in your GEM PATH folder shown by `gem env`, then do a `gem update --system`. and of course proxy server gets in the way of Step 2.

Is this issue with gems fixed in some later release that I can download ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well another battle ends.. with a victory.
Turns out the proxy server can be specified after all. However the documented `-p` and `--http-proxy` command line switches don't work for some reason or I wasn't smart enough to figure out the right incantation.

```
>ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
>gem -v
1.3.5 
>gem query -p http
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
    invalid argument: -p http
```

Just for trying everything I could I tried setting the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable on the windows command line as mentioned in the WolfByte's answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm) (that i stumbled upon after search keyword bingo on google). AND IT WORKED!!!

```
>SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:port
>gem update --system
>gem install rails
```

Guess SO needs a new tag-line "**The answer is in there**" ala XFiles. You just need to wrestle with Google to get to it. Hope this helps the next person

Comment: "gem update --system" is an imporant step, despite seeming to do nothing.  Thanks!

Comment: if you happen to use powershell console in windows, use: $env:HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy:port", do not use the set command as it is aliased to set-variable in powershell which won't set your environment variable. This bit me a few times :)