# Facing lot of problems while using ROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have read many article regarding easy installing steps. I installed ruby on windows. After starting the server i got welcome message too. After that if i add a controller I got this message on browser.

And also when tried to do a rake db:migrate i get the error saying mysql gem is missing.

I have installed mysql 5.0. I tried updating gem using this command and got this error.

C:\Documents and Settings\dchannap\Desktop>gem install mysql
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql' (>= 0) in any repository

My gem version is 1.3.7. and ruby is 1.9.1.

Can anyone help me in this regard. I hav to do a project on ROR..

Comment: It's not solving so i maked this comment:
You will find Rails much more fun if you were using Linux for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably internet connection or server side problem.

Here is similair [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238340/how-can-i-get-past-http-gems-rubyforge-org-does-not-appear-to-be-a-repository)

Comment: Even i feel its a internet problem. I dono how to use proxy. Can u help on that.

Comment: You can find the proxy in the settings of your favourite browser.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it much easier to get started using SQLite3. Why not go with the flow for now? When you need to go more advanced you'll have much more experience with Ruby and Rails and Gems and you'll find it much easier to get sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? In that case you will have to specify it. E.g.

```
gem install --http-proxy http://your-proxy-address:8080 mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies.. I learnt Rails on Windows will face problems. And just tried with Instant rails. I faced no problems at all. I am able run small applicatins now.