# Michael Hartl's rails 2.3 tutorial Installing RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following this tutorial book that involves signing up and user creation for my application that I am developing. 
Now as per chapter 3 in the book, Michael asks us to install Rspec for Testing the application step by step.
after putting the codes like:

[sudo] gem install rspec -v 1.3.0

[sudo] gem install rspec-rails -v 1.3.2

I get the following errors.

ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository

ERROR:  could not find gem rspec locally or in a repository

I have been trying to install and update my rails too but I keep getting this error..
I agree there are some security measures that are involved from my institution for downloading plugins and libraries, and after confirming with them I have been offered privileges with new proxy and port settings.
I have read many threads involving this error message from the terminal but none solved my issue.
Would be grateful if some one could clear this big problem
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238340/how-can-i-get-past-http-gems-rubyforge-org-does-not-appear-to-be-a-repository)?