# More gem install rails headache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Trying to install rails on windows. Downloaded the latest ruby exec and installed it, downloaded, unpacked rails. Upon gem install rails I get the dreaded

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly  respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

What I've done so far:

- Checked my proxy (I'm behind the company proxy), added the -p option, --http-proxy and all possible variations of the proxy URL, to no avail
- Tried removing/adding another source besides rubygems.org, doesn't work either
- Downloaded and unpacked rails source, can't seem to be able to install it either

This is very discouraging and getting quite annoying. I should mention I have no choice but to use windows

Comment: This might be helpful to you -> 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238340/how-can-i-get-past-http-gems-rubyforge-org-does-not-appear-to-be-a-repository

Comment: It's basically variations around the proxy switch, which I've tried already

Answer (score 0):

I have followed [this](http://rubyinstaller.org/) link for installing ruby with RubyInstaller. For Rails you should follow [this](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=34) link. If you follow these 2 links you will able to install Ruby as well as Rails in windows. I have used this 2 links with great effect and it works for me.

Comment: I have Ruby and gem already, the Rails link just says run gem install rails, which is precisely what isn't working. I'm nearly certain it's the proxy, but why doesn't the -p switch work ?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, with also a proxy probably being the problem. From another forum post of mine I was directed to this link: https://github.com/rails/rails/downloads where I was able to download Rails manually. Now I just have to figure out how to install it manually. And hope it doesn't have a million dependencies.

Here is the link to the other forum: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/26224?r=26230#message-26230

My other two forum posts have not yeilded any takers yet, other than one person telling me what I already know about dependencies.

[Redmine installation - ruby rails 2.3.11 manual download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449692/redmine-installation-ruby-rails-2-3-11-manual-download)