# Redmine installation - ruby rails 2.3.11 manual download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

I am having a very hard time finding Rails 2.3.11 to download. I am trying to install this on Windows XP which Redmine 1.2.x requires [this version](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Ruby-38-Ruby-on-Rails-38-Rack). When I try to install the gem through the command prompt this is what I get:

```
C:\>gem install rails -v=2.3.11
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (=2.3.11) in any repository
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Errno::ETIMEOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party ddi not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I believe this problem is due to my highly secured internet connection. So I would like to manually download Rails 2.3.11. But I cannot find it. It seems it should be here: http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=307 but the needed version 2.3.11 is not listed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/2.3.11 ?

With manual installation you may get problems with dependecies (the needed gems must be loaded again manual when you use `gem install xxx --local`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
gem install -v=2.3.11 rails
```