# how to update watir?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

i am getting error while truing to install watir

C:>gem install watir
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'watir' (>= 0) in any repository

C:>gem -v
1.3.7

C:>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: The last time I have tried, Watir worked only with Ruby 1.8, and I see you are using 1.9. It does not solve your problem, but try with Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
```

and then

```
gem install watir
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution (since I can't vote yet):

```
gem install watir --source http://gems.github.com
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a proxy problem.  Use http_proxy environment variable to setup a tunnel, or download the gems manually from rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post useful in setting the http_proxy value and then installing.

[How do I update Ruby Gems from behind a Proxy (ISA-NTLM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm)

Looks like this is an old post - but there was nothing marked as the answer :)