# Error While installing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, watir

I am facing the following error while installing the gems on windows machine.

They were couple of similar questions on the stack overflow,but that didn't help.

My system Configurations

```
Windows:7
Ruby:2.2

Error:ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'watir' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Comment: Do you have something like this:  `gem "watir", "~>4.0"` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @ K M Rakibul Islam gem 'watir', '5.0.0', these is the gem of version I have

Comment: I see, you can check this out and try those sugestions if that works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172108/how-to-update-watir

Comment: may be you are having internet issues

Comment: @ K M Rakibul Islam I have tried that it didn't work

Comment: @ Zahid 51 lol..........its fine no issue at all

Comment: @ K M Rakibul Islam ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'watir' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://gems.github.com/ - Errno::ECONNREF
USED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
. - connect(2) for "gems.github.com" port 80 (http://gems.github.com/specs.4.8.g
z) when I tried with the link specifed I got the above error

Comment: whats the output of this: `gem sources`

Comment: try doing: `gem sources --add http://rubygems.org/`

Comment: I got these error  with the above command Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
Error fetching http://rubygems.org/:
        Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target mach
ine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 80 (http://api
.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it looks like you're missing the rubygems registry from your Gemfile sources (which is likely where you want to get watir from). Add this in at the top of your Gemfile `source 'https://rubygems.org'`