# "bad response Proxy Authentication" when using gem on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows-xp, rubygems

When I try to add source:

```
C:\>gem source --verbose --add http://gemcutter.org

GET http://gemcutter.org/specs.4.8.gz
407 Proxy Authentication Required
Error fetching http://gemcutter.org:
    bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://gemcutter.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

p.s. my Windows XP client accesses the web via a proxy, so I tried:

```
C:\>gem -v
1.8.10

C:\>gem source --verbose --http-proxy http://192.168.10.24:3128 --add http://gemcutter.org
```

but returns the same error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the proxy username and password in there somehow.

On *nix machines, gem looks for an environment variable named `HTTP_PROXY`.  You can set this variable on windows too.

Run `SET HTTP_PROXY=http://%USER%:%PASSWORD%@192.168.10.24:3128` before you run your `gem` command.

---

Another possibility is to install another "proxy" on your computer itself.  See [How do I update Ruby Gems from behind a Proxy (ISA-NTLM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm) and http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/ for details on this.

---

You might be able to use [rubysspi](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubysspi/).  See the instructions [here](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/installing-ruby/#install-windows).