# How to install Compass on Windows

Tags: compass-sass, ruby-1.9.3

I have installed Ruby on my system, and now I want to install Compass. But when I execute the `gem install compass` command, it shows an error like this:

```
could not find valid gem 'compass' <>=0> in any repositary
```

And also:

```
SocketError: getadressinfo: no such host is known.<http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz>
```

I don't know what the problem is. If I run `ruby -v`, it shows the Ruby version. So what's the problem with installing Compass?

Can anyone explain this to me properly? I've searched Google, but all I could find was some proxy problem - and I couldn't understand how to set the proxy at all.

I'm using Windows and a company internet connection, so I don't know the username and password of my proxy.

Answer (score 10):

I was behind a proxy and HumberFrench's solution above helped:

Go to Ruby bin folder:

```
cd c:/Ruby193/bin
```

And then install compass gem:

```
gem install compass --http-proxy http://<proxy_adreess>:<port_of_proxy>
```

Another tip: am on Aptana Studio, so this could be run from within Aptana's terminal.

Cant up-vote so adding this here.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, finally solved it manually.
Goto the rubygems [compass](https://rubygems.org/gems/compass) page, and download the gem by clicking the *Download* link. Scroll down and you will see three *Runtime Dependencies*. Goto each of them and download those gems also. Put all of them in a directory, and try

```
gem install downloaded_compass_filename
```

This should solve your problem.
If it gives an repository not found error message, you can force gem to try local files through the `gem --local install` option

Answer (score 4):

if you use a proxy, and get error, do it

```
gem install compass --http-proxy http://<proxy_adreess>:<port_of_proxy>
```

gem install -h gives you a lor of options

Answer (score 3):

The proxy is the most likely cause. You will have to get permission from the network admin, or manually download compass. For more info, See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm) SA post.

If you decide to go the manual route here is a [link](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass) to the RubyGems compass page. This not ideal, but also better than having to write css without compass magic ^^

Good luck!

Comment: no use, i tried 
gem install --http-proxy http://localhost:8080 compass 

but same error.. pls some one give solution.

Comment: It sounds like there is an issue with your ENV. Have you tried setting the proxy configuration in your gem.bat file, instead of directly on the command line?

Comment: Can u tel me how to set proxy configuration in gem bat file

Answer (score 3):

On windows i had a few instalations of ruby:

```
    C:\ruby187
```

and

```
    C:\Ruby200-x64
```

install compass in both places, using:

```
    gem install compass
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running the install command in the bin folder.

```
$ cd C:\Your_Ruby_Folder\bin
$ gem install compass
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and i resolve it with.

1. Uninstall ruby end deleted folder ruby
2. Download ruby version 1.9.x
3. After thet install sass
4. last stem: install compass