# Ruby on Rails issue in Windows 7 behind websense and firewall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, proxy, firewall

Regarding Ruby on rails in windows 7. after installing the railsinstaller, I am facing lot of issue and not sure what the cause is?

PS: I posted this question on stack-overflow, somewhere else while looking for answer of similar issue, where a gentleman suggest me to put my question on separate thread. And here it goes.

The windows 7 is behind proxy and websense. I run all applications as administrator. I wonder if I left any site/blog for the issues I am facing. Though it is my first question here on ROR in stack-overflow after I exhausted options of reading and searching to resolve it.

I am even not able to do the

```
$ gem install rubygems-update
```

though I the path is correct and showing

```
c:\>gem sources
```

display

```
http://rubygems.org.
```

as the only source.

I am still getting the below error for the even simple database creation. That was given  in root directory of sample rails project namely SampleROR.
Any help please.

```
$ rake db:create
The i18n gem is not available. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- i18n
c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/home/anil-ku/SampleROR/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/home/anil-ku/SampleROR/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/home/anil-ku/SampleROR/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Note that I am not able to do

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

with latest version of rails, installed using railsinstaller one click for windows.
I did the bundle install after this, that run successfully but the issue didn't disappear.

```
anil-ku@hostname ~/SampleROR
$ bundle install
Using rake (10.0.2)
**Using i18n (0.6.1)**
Using multi_json (1.4.0)
Using activesupport (3.2.1)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.1)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.3)
Using actionpack (3.2.1)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.1)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.35)
Using activerecord (3.2.1)
Using activeresource (3.2.1)
Using bundler (1.0.22)
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.7.5)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.2.1)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (2.1.4)
Using rails (3.2.1)
Using sass (3.2.3)
Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6)
Using uglifier (1.3.0)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.

anil-ku@DS-7071BC8FD6C4 ~/SampleROR
**$ bundle show i18n**
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1
```

when I list

```
$gem list -local
actionmailer (3.2.1)
actionpack (3.2.1)
activemodel (3.2.9, 3.2.1)
activerecord (3.2.1)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.1)
activeresource (3.2.1)
activesupport (3.2.9, 3.2.1)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.22)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0, 1.2.0)
columnize (0.3.6)
daemons (1.1.9)
debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.5)
deprecated (3.0.1, 2.0.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0, 1.3.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hike (1.2.1)
hoe (3.3.1)
**i18n (0.6.1, 0.6.0)**
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4, 1.0.2)
jquery-rails (2.1.4)
json (1.7.5, 1.5.4)
mail (2.4.4, 2.4.1)
mime-types (1.19, 1.17.2)
minitest (4.3.3, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.4.0, 1.3.7, 1.1.0)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
permutation (0.1.8)
pg (0.13.1 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2, 1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1)
rails (3.2.1)
railties (3.2.1)
rake (10.0.2, 0.9.2.2)
rake-compiler (0.8.1)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubyzip (0.9.6.1)
sass (3.2.3)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sdoc (0.3.20)
sprockets (2.1.3, 2.1.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.6 x86-mingw32, 1.3.5 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
tiny_tds (0.5.1 x86-mingw32)
treetop (1.4.12, 1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.35, 0.3.31)
uglifier (1.3.0)
```

It shows i18n installed. Not sure what is the issue.

```
$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.1
```

also, downloading gem package and run it using **ruby setup.rb** also didn't work

```
C:\RailsInstaller\rubygems>ruby setup.rb
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:480:in `find_files': undefined method `map' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1085:in `load_plugins'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/rubygems/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from setup.rb:25:in `<main>'

C:\RailsInstaller\rubygems>
```

My gem version is

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem -v
1.8.16
```

I tried to download gem manually from site (from http://rubygems.org/gems/)  and installed few of them. So able to install some while for most other gems it give error like below

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install mongrel
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install mongrel_services
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install mongrel_service
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install mongrel_service-0.4.0.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install mongrel-1.1.5.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install mongrel2-0.34.0.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install win32-api-1.4.8.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed win32-api-1.4.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for win32-api-1.4.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for win32-api-1.4.8...

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install windows-api-0.4.2.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

Finally my environment details for gem is

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.16
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/anil-ku/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>
```

I note that there is nothing like ruby folder under 
 C:/Users/anil-ku/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
the only thing under the above one is a folder named specs that looks irrelevant.

Also the path environment is windows is

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>echo %PATH%
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\c
md;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Gi
t\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\Syste
m32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;C:\Program Files\cvsnt;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;d:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;d:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9
.3\bin
```

Any help for how to proceed for simple database connection with above and/or how to install gem fully?

Comment: Not a real answer to your problem, but the best solution. I did RoR on windows for many years. It is almost all pain. Finally I installed ubuntu on a [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and now I do all my ruby development on ubuntu. RoR and ruby are very unixy. Alot of the gems only works on unix. Testing is really slow on windows. There are workarounds, but they consume time. If you want to spend your time developing, go buy a mac or install ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your proxy settings for rubygems.  For example set the Environment Variable like so:

SET HTTP_PROXY=http://wolfbyte:secret@pigsy:8080

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4431/192221