# Gem install hangs indefinitely

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, rvm

Background: I'm a designer that works well with HTML, CSS, and JS. But when it comes to setting up my environment is where I fall short.

I recently purchased a home computer. I want to set up [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/getting-started/) to use in a project. I already installed rvm and all its requirements. I am on ruby-2.0.0-p0, which from what I understand is the latest stable release.

When I attempt to install Middleman, or any other gem for that matter, nothing happens. The cursor just moves to the next line. [image: Screenshot]

Some guidance, or troubleshooting steps, would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Ricardo

Comment: For me, this was actually the ipv6 issue described in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442766/gem-install-error-timed-out-https-api-rubygems-org

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If `gem install` is hanging, it's most likely a network, proxy, or firewall issue on your end.

You can investigate by issuing your gem install command in verbose mode with `-V`.  It'll show you what URLs it's communicating with to download the gem, and you can hopefully see what it's doing and where it's hanging:

```
> gem install -V middleman
HEAD https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
...
```

You can also check [status.rubygems.org](http://status.rubygems.org/) where they'll alert you in case the gem/spec servers do have problems (see screenshot below):

[image: RubyGem.org status screenshot]

Comment: This was the reason and this is the solution for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm

Comment: try again after turn off your proxy and vpn stuff

Comment: Is there any method to try when `gem update -V` does not output anything?

Answer (score 8):

Found my problem! I was runnning ruby 1.8.7. I needed to update my .zshrc file to use 1.9.3 as default.

What I did was put this on my .zshrc file:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue with ruby bundled with MacOS.
Installing a new version of Ruby helped.

```
brew install ruby
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
gem install <my gem>
```

Hope it helps someone.
Please note step with ~/.zshrc might need to be adjusted if you are using bash.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be on *Mac*. Have you `Xcode` installed?

The cite from `MiddleMan` official:

> Mac OS X comes prepackaged with both Ruby and Rubygems, however, some
>   of the Middleman's dependencies need to be compiled during
>   installation and on OS X that requires Xcode. Xcode can be installed
>   via the [Mac App
>   Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12).
>   Alternately, if you have a free Apple Developer account, you can just
>   install Command Line Tools for Xcode from their [downloads
>   page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

BTW, just out of curiousity, is your connection OK? Try to run `ping google.com` in the sibling terminal during `gem install …`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mudasobwa :). I do have XCode installed, as well as Command Line Tools installed. I ran ping google.com and it is showing that I have a connection. Nothing seems to be working unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone, my terminal was hanging on

```
gem update --system
```

and changing it to

```
sudo gem update --system
```

fixed it.