# gem install error: timed out https://api.rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, ubuntu-18.04

I am failing to install `bundler`. I am on Ubuntu 18 and have ruby 2.5.1 installed. Here is the output of running this command.

```
gem install bundler --debug

NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `LoadError' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/resolv.rb:170 - LoadError
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:939 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:114 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:997 - execution expired
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:306 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:232 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/ikushlianski/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:325 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /home/ikushlianski/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/prerelease_specs.4.8
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:939 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:114 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:997 - execution expired
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:306 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:232 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/ikushlianski/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:325 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /home/ikushlianski/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/specs.4.8
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:939 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:114 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:997 - execution expired
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:306 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:269 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:72 - Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'bundler (>= 0)'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:232 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/ikushlianski/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/ikushlianski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:325 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /home/ikushlianski/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/latest_specs.4.8
```

Running `sudo gem install bundler` outputs `sudo: gem: command not found`

Comment: Are you able to reach https://rubygems.org from this machine? because `Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out`

Comment: `curl https://rubygems.org` seems to work fine. It outputs some html

Comment: And `https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz` ?

Comment: Yeah, it outputs some gzipped content, no errors

Comment: Weird, can you `gem install whatever` successfully ?

Comment: I found similar issue on rubygems help center, http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/31074-timeout-error
It seems to be an ipv6 resolution issue

Comment: ok, thank you, maybe I have to try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling IPv6 on your Ubuntu

Comment: That is THE answer. It works now, thank you. According to this article https://www.admintome.com/blog/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu-18-04/, ipv6 will be enabled as soon as I reboot. Is this what I should expect? I don't want ipv6 disabled in future.

Comment: Crazy that it's a year later and this is still a problem.

Comment: Applies to Windows 10, as well. Could not install gems until I disabled IPv6