# NTLM authentication and smartcards

Tags: authentication, proxy, ntlm

I'm running a program (Mathematica) in a VMWare VPC behind a corporate internet proxy. Various programs installed in that VPC like IE, Chrome, Excel, Word, Acrobat Reader, and even MS Paint get data from the Internet without problems, but Mathematica doesn't seem to handle the proxy correctly.

My guess is it's not able to handle the proxy's NTLM authentication.

In an earlier situation, behind a different firewall, I had some success with [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) as an intermediate between Mathematica and the proxy. CNTLM talks to the proxy and takes care of the NTLM authentication, and Mathematica is given the port CNTLM listens to and ip address (localhost), to talk to. However, in that earlier case I knew the credentials to be used for the proxy (i.e., my own).

In the current situation, my logon takes place using a smartcard and a PIN. The VPC gets credentials passed transparently (I don't have to enter them) and apparently all the programs I mentioned above automagically know about them. This makes me think Mathematica or CNTLM should be able to do this as well. However, my PIN used as password doesn't work (in fact, I get locked out if I try too often). I assume that the credentials used are in fact not my own but are either the windows password (that I don't have as smartcard user) or are derived from my PIN and smartcard.

My question is: how can I make this setup work? This may involve CNTLM, but other solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: Did you check the _Internet Connectivity_ dialog, accessed from the _Help_  menu? What's the response if you use _Check Internet Connectivity_?

Comment: @likeitlikeit I did all that and I already nailed the prime cause of the problem to Mathematica's inability to deal with NTLM authentication. I've discussed this with Wolfram Research already and they agreed that MMA can't do NTLM at the moment. In this question I'm asking for a workaround for the problem that I encountered with my usual workaround for this problem. CNTLM helps with apllications that don't do NTLM, but the problem in this case is that CNTLM doesn't work with single-sign-on environments where the authentication is not to be obtained from a direct username/password entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have a chance by using a browser proxy such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)

Like CNTLM also Fiddler act as a local proxy and allow applications that support proxy, but do not support NTLM (they support a “plain” proxy) to use the corporate proxy not directly but through a local proxy.

Unlike CNTLM , Fiddler doesn't require to configure the credentials but it uses the current user crediatials to authenticate the web requests.

I Can't be sure that this is the solution for you , since I haven't an enviroment like your,  but this workaround works in some other cases as reported in this 
[answer about ruby gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187271/1657028)
or/and this [blog about mercurial](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/hgtk/issue/1620/proxy-authentication-over-ntlm-for-isa) so I hope this can work with *Mathematica* too.

Note: Once you run Fiddler it automatically configure the browser proxy to itself ( `http://localhost:8888` ) therefore you can leave the proxy settings of your application to **"Use Proxy Settings from My System or Browser"**. By the way Fiddler it's not only a local proxy and could be used also to troubleshooting or debugging, the feature list is available in [here](http://fiddler2.com/features)