# Can't install Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raspberry-pi

I tried installing Ruby on Rails by following this guide: http://elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails

when reach to command

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

I got message

```
RROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why: 
Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If so check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm

Comment: No i don't behind a proxy

Comment: did you ever try without the --rails parameter? You can still install rails after rvm/ruby