# Error installing nokogiri, permission denied

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When I type "gem install nokogiri" I receive the error:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno: EACCES)
    Permission denied - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/1.9/nokogiri.so
```

I have no idea what I need to do to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have "C:/RailsInstaller/" directory?  what happens when you type "MD C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/1.9/" ?

Comment: It says "A subdirectory or file _____ already exists"

Comment: can you create any file in that directory?

Comment: Yeah, I just cd'd into there and ran "touch new" and it created the file

Comment: Hold on, I just ran "gem list" and nokogiri shows up. Could that be why it's not working?

Comment: My guess would be that you installed in an elevated `Administrator` prompt. Try running `gem uni nokogiri -v 1.6.0` in a regular then if it doesn't work in an elevated prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below :

```
gem install --http-proxy http://localhost:3128 _name_of_gem_
```

look here - [`How do I update Ruby Gems from behind a Proxy (ISA-NTLM)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got bundle install to work after installing gems bindex, msgpack, bootsnap, byebug, childprocess, ffi puma, and sqlite3

I came to this conclusion by sudo installing each gem after I attempted to bundle install, once it through an Error it told me what gem I needed

```
 In Gemfile:

     puma
```