# Unable to install nokogiri using rvm, receiving "nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2"

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, rvm, debian

If I try to install nokogiri, I receive the following error:

```
rvmsudo gem install nokogiri
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

If I check my ruby version, it tells me I am running ruby1.9.3

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]
```

If I use `printenv`, these are my env variables:

```
rvm_bin_path=/home/jenkins/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=/home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@nokogiri
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-color
IRBRC=/home/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/.irbrc
HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448
USER=jenkins
rvm_path=/home/jenkins/.rvm
L1=-
rvm_prefix=/home/jenkins
MAIL=/var/mail/jenkins
PATH=/home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@nokogiri/bin:/home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/home/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/jenkins/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
PWD=/home/jenkins
LANG=C
rvm_version=1.21.3 (stable)
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/jenkins
LOGNAME=jenkins
GEM_PATH=/home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@nokogiri:/home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global
install_flag=1
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.3-p448
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

I have some pretty bad luck with RVM and rather than break my entire installation, I thought I'd ask here.

Why can't I proceed with the installation of nokogiri?

I'm on Debian.

Answer (score 4):

Just try `gem install nokogiri` as you have *RVM* installed. See here [`Installing Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) for other things to install with it.

Like below :

```
# nokogiri requirements
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
gem install nokogiri
```

See [`my answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331282/error-installing-nokogiri-permission-denied/17370399?noredirect=1#comment25215682_17370399) here for the part *ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) ` Permission denied*

Comment: The prerequisites are already installed:

`libxml2-dev is already the newest version.`
`libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.`
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

As user "jenkins", I need elevated privileges:

`jenkins@jenkins-ci-02:~$ gem install nokogiri`
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)`
`    Permission denied - /home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@nokogiri/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0`

Should I be "root"?

Comment: I'm not sure that helps me.  I found an installer directory here: `/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/scripts/functions/installer` and here: `/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/functions/installer`  I was able to create the following file without any issues, as user "jenkins" - `touch /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/new`  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have the luxury of starting from scratch so I'm going to do just that.  I have yet to find a solution to this.  If I get a good installation, I'll share my steps to building a server from scratch, which may not help others with this problem on a server that can't be rebuilt but that's all I have to offer.

Comment: @harperville, did you manage to resolve this problem. I'm getting the same error, I have the same vesion environment as you.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an older version of nokogiri (1.5.11) to chef cookbook and it worked fine after OR manually add it on the server:

chef_gem "nokogiri" do
   action :install
   version "1.5.11"
   compile_time false if respond_to?(:compile_time)
end

OR

## /usr/local/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/gem install nokogiri --version=1.5.11

(use absolute path where u see the error; means /my_path/gem install nokogiri).