# Why is Gems not able to install rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

My gem version is

> 1.8.15

I am trying to execute the following command :

> sudo gem install rails

but showing errors as :

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>       bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

I already have my apt.conf file updated with proxy and username password details . What could be the problem happening here ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm

Comment: I tried 3-4 suggestions and none of them are working . I have tried using export command as mentioned , then using -p option with gem , then using set HTTP_PROXY as well . My sudo apt-get install works fine with the setting I have in apt.conf file . So why is this not working ?