# Why is Rubygems not able to install Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to install rails using the command

> gem install rails

on my ubuntu 12.04 . Also I have configured my apt.conf file with the username , password and proxy details . Then too the execution of this command gives an error as :

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPServerException)
>     407 "Proxy Authentication Required"

If I run

> sudo gem install rails

the errors are :

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
>       Unable to resolve dependencies: treetop requires polyglot (>= 0), polyglot (>= 0.3.1); sprockets requires tilt (!= 1.3.0, ~> 1.1)

My local gem list is as follows :

> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>       actionmailer (4.0.1)
>   actionpack (4.0.1)
>   activemodel (4.0.1)
>   activerecord (4.0.1)
>   activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
>   activesupport (4.0.1)
>   arel (4.0.1)
>   atomic (1.1.14)
>   bigdecimal (1.2.0)
>   builder (3.1.4)
>   bundler (1.3.5)
>   bundler-unload (1.0.2)
>   coffee-rails (4.0.1)
>   coffee-script (2.2.0)
>   coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
>   erubis (2.7.0)
>   execjs (2.0.2)
>   executable-hooks (1.2.6)
>   hike (1.2.3)
>   i18n (0.6.5)
>   io-console (0.4.2)
>   jbuilder (1.5.2)
>   jquery-rails (3.0.4)
>   json (1.8.1, 1.7.7)
>   mail (2.5.4)
>   mime-types (1.25)
>   minitest (4.7.5, 4.3.2)
>   multi_json (1.8.2)
>   polyglot (0.3.3)
>   psych (2.0.0)
>   rack (1.5.2)
>   rack-test (0.6.2)
>   rails (4.0.1)
>   railties (4.0.1)
>   rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6)
>   rdoc (4.0.1, 4.0.0, 3.12.2)
>   rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
>   rvm (1.11.3.8)
>   sass (3.2.12)
>   sass-rails (4.0.1)
>   sdoc (0.3.20)
>   sprockets (2.10.0)
>   sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
>   sqlite3 (1.3.8)
>   test-unit (2.0.0.0)
>   thor (0.18.1)
>   thread_safe (0.1.3)
>   tilt (1.4.1)
>   treetop (1.4.15)
>   turbolinks (1.3.0)
>   tzinfo (0.3.38)
>   uglifier (2.3.0)

I have already run "rvm requirements" and I have tried using SET HTTP_PROXY but it also doesn't have any affect . What should I do ?

**EDIT:**

I tried using

> export http_proxy=http://${username}:${password}@${proxy}:${port}

and then ran gem install rails and it worked ...

Comment: What about trying `sudo gem install rails`?

Comment: @sawa : now showing these errors :
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: treetop requires polyglot (>= 0), polyglot (>= 0.3.1); sprockets requires tilt (!= 1.3.0, ~> 1.1)

Comment: What about installing the dependencies manually?

Comment: @sawa : yes , would have installed but that should be also through gem install . I got into the trouble at the first because I tried sudo apt-get install rails and that messed up everything .And I don't understand that if my tilt and polyglot versions are newer in my gem list , why is it still showing such errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Gems not able to install rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860225/why-is-gems-not-able-to-install-rails)

Answer (score 1):

super user and normal user has different gem list.
I think super user does not have polyglot and tilt.

Try:

```
sudo gem install polyglot
sudo gem install tilt
```

Please check gem list of super user.

```
sudo gem list
```