# Install Ruby gems behind NTLM proxy

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ntlm

I am trying to install ruby gems behind NTLM proxy. My OS is Windows 7. These are all the solutions that I tried, non of them working.

**Using HTTP_PROXY:**

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
set HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
set HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080/
```

All above response bad URI

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
```

Response: bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407

**Using -p or --http-proxy parameter from Ruby**

```
gem install -p "http://domain\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080" rake

gem install -p "http://domain\\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080" rake

gem install -p http://domain\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080 rake

gem install -p http://domain\\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080 rake

gem install --http-proxy "http://domain\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080" rake

gem install --http-proxy "http://domain\\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080" rake

gem install --http-proxy http://domain\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080 rake

gem install --http-proxy http://domain\\user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080 rake
```

All response: invalid argument

```
Try all the options above without the domain or encode the \ to %5C will receive reponse: bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407
```

What did I miss in these command or setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cntlm` http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/, so that you have a local proxy that requires no authentication (which in turns connects to the ntlm proxy).

Also: [How do I update Ruby Gems from behind a Proxy (ISA-NTLM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm?rq=1)

Comment: for  detailed instruction on CNTLM please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24540105/1802348

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no fix for the moment to make work rubygems behind an NTLM proxy: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/360.
Anyway, I still found no way to fix it and the only solution is to download a gem (take care of all its dependencies) and install locally (from inside a folder where the gem was saved to):

```
gem install your_gem_name --local
```

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled on a more easier and possibly safer solution that works not just for git but also any command based installers

- Rubygems in ruby
- npm in node

One solution running all your traffic from command line is proxied with authentiction.

**Wont expose your password in the user:password@domain:port format**

**Solution:**

Download [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), It has a built in way to add authentication headers to all requests.

Once running menu Rules-> Automatically Authenticate (Tick that)

Then for git

```
git config --global http.proxy http://localhost:8888
git config --global https.proxy http://localhost:8888
```

Thats it!