# Installing Bundler Gem Behind Proxy

Tags: ruby, windows, proxy, bundler

I'm having trouble installing the bundler gem from behind my proxy server.

```
$ gem install bundler --http-proxy http://my.proxy/proxy.pac:80
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found 404 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.1

$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
```

Anyone have suggestions on how to resolve these errors?

Comment: Can you get any other gems? Or is it the problem specific to bundler?

Comment: No I can't. I get the same error on any gem I try.

Comment: Can you access the internet through other means such as apt-get (assuming you are on linux)?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 SP 1

Comment: I'm getting Ping request could not find host http://rubygems.org.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with working behind a proxy on windows. On linux I had to set environment variables to force these types of requests out through the proxy.

Answer (score 4):

From  `gem help install` documentation:

```
sudo gem install bundler -p http://myawesome.proxy.com:1234
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

sudo HTTP_PROXY="http://10.3.100.207:8080" gem install bundler

Replace "10.3.100.207" with your host and "8080" with your "port value"

Or try this:

sudo HTTP_PROXY="http://10.3.100.207:8080" or sudo export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.3.100.207:8080"

Also do with https and HTTPS as I faced problem once due to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gem supports evaluating a `.pac` file. You need to give it the correct proxy configuration directly.

Comment: You are correct. I'm now getting a 407 error however: `$ gem install bundler --http-proxy http://myusername:mypassword@my.proxy:8080
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Proxy Authentication Required 407 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)`

Comment: Try using environment variables, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382152/29470