# Ruby gem install comes up with timeout error every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Trying to install gems always comes up with error. Always have to download them manually thru browser for some reason. Is there something I'm missing here?

Here is install example:

```
$ gem install mysql2 --debug -V
```

NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued

```
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0                                                                                      /win32/registry.rb:250 - No more data is available.
Exception `Resolv::ResolvTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/                                                                                      resolv.rb:694 - Resolv::ResolvTimeout
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:880 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:112 - execution expired
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:297 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/Users/anking/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:880 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:112 - execution expired
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:297 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/Users/anking/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:880 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:112 - execution expired
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:297 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:265 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:71 - Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'mysql2 (>= 0)'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql2' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/Users/anking/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:316 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - C:/Users/anking/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/latest_specs.4.8
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:880 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882 - execution expired
Exception `Net::OpenTimeout' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:112 - execution expired
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:297 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError' at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:265 - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? (See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm )

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy and i can download gems thru browser no problem

Comment: It could be related to ipV6 issues with rubygems.org, see: http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/31074-timeout-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is 7 months old now. As [ipd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415409/ipd) references, on both Mac and Windows, temporarily disabling the IPv6 stack allowed my `bundle install` request to complete without hiccup.