Ruby bundler cannot reach rubygems.org
I wanted to create a new rails app. Then, I ran bundle install but it always gave me the following error:
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Gem::Net::OpenTimeout: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (execution expired) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

I can reach the rubygems.org website from my browser. I tried everything I could think of, but nothing worked.
This seems to be a problem with gem, since gem install bundler gives the exact same error.
gem env:
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.5.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.3.4 (2024-07-09 patchlevel 94) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/aino/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/aino/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/aino/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/aino/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/aino/.cache/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/aino/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/aino/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
     - /home/aino/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/aino/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin
     - /usr/lib64/rbenv/libexec
     - /home/aino/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/aino/.opam/default/bin
     - /home/aino/.local/bin
     - /run/user/1000/fnm_multishells/4864_1724445534233/bin
     - /home/aino/.local/share/fnm
     - /home/aino/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/aino/.cargo/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/sbin


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470730/ruby-gem-install-comes-up-with-timeout-error-every-time

This link points to an issue rubygems.org had over six years ago. Turning off ipv6 can't still be the solution to this, right?
